# Conflict with jQuery + Prototype + Opera / IE

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I'm using IPBoard CMS that comes with prototype and I use the latest jQuery.

I've implemented a jQuery gallery picture viewer:
- It works fine on Chrome and Firefox.
- I have troubles with Opera and IE 8.

I've created a minimal example here: http://www.warriorlabs.net/index.php?app=ccs&module=pages&section=pages&folder=&id=22

You just have to click on the picture.

In IE 8 or Opera:

When I remove prototype everything works fine.

When I keep prototype with jQuery altogether with my "noConflicted" gallery viewer there seems to be errors with the width and height returned by jQuery accessors. As a result the loading box is not centered and the picture itself seems to be mapped to the whole window.

Has anyone got a clue of why this is happening ?

A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually worked with both prototype and jQuery at the same time, but by my understanding you should put the `jQuery.noConflict()` call before the prototype script.

Try changing your document head to something like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.4/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.warriorlabs.net/jScript/facebox/facebox.js"></script>
</head>
```

***EDIT:***
Also remove the `jQuery.noConflict()` from the first line in `facebox.js` as it removes the `$` function defined by prototype.

***SIDE NOTE:***
The usual way of writing jQuery plugins is something like this:

```
(function($){
  //Inside this block we know that $ == jQuery
  //The global $ (i.e. window.$) might be something else
  //By using this anonymous function we make sure we don't polute the global namespace
  var v = "function scope";//this is a variable in the scope of the function
  window.globalV = "global scope";//this is a global variable
  $.fn.myPlugin = function(){
    //my plugin code, usually something like:
    return this.each(function(){
      //do something with each element
      $(this).show();
    });
    //returning this.each allows for chaining
  }
})(jQuery);
```

---

In Chrome I get this error on your demo page:
`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function [prototype.js:4598]`

Comment: Hey Dan, I've applied your fix to the page. So far I have the same issue though. Do you still have the error ?

Comment: Try to also remove the `jQuery.noConflict()` from the first line in `facebox.js`

Comment: Tried this. It does not change anything probably because facebox is written with jQuery not protoype. Indeed in my example prototype is never "used" it's just there :). So I think prototype is corrupting jQuery or something, probably not the opposite.

Comment: Perhaps ... in this case you might try to move the `prototype.js` script at the top of the head tag. It might also be the case that prototype modifies the actual prototype of HTMLElement in such a way that it messes up the objects/functions jQuery expects.

Comment: Maybe somebody else can help you, because I have very little experience with prototype ... sorry

Comment: No problem, I've already used prototype altogether with jQuery + noConflict. I think I'm facing something really specific here. Kind of like this : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie-jquery-and-prototype-conflict

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track ... perhaps you might be able to make it work by doing something like `Element.scrollTo=undefined;` right at the beginning of `facebox.js`. Of course this might break prototype code that relies on it ...

Comment: See definitive, albeit inelegant solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved if you comment out the following code in the prototype core code. But this is perhaps not the best solution if you ever need to use the scrollto function.

```
    //Commented out because of the conflict with jQuery.
  //scrollTo: function(element) {
   // element = $(element);
   // var pos = Element.cumulativeOffset(element);
   // window.scrollTo(pos[0], pos[1]);
   // return element;
 // },
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar problem (jQuery - prototype conflict error in IE8) switching jquery 1.4.2 to 1.5.